# Only certain plot points responding to row selection in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to adapt an example (2.1.1) from the tutorial found [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) on interactive plots in shiny. I have a shiny app as follows:

Data:

```
seats = data.table(
ID = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"),
Row = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
SeatNum = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
y = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
price = 45)
```

ui.R

```
fluidPage(

title = 'Select Table Rows',

h1('A Client-side Table'),

fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x1')),
    column(6, plotOutput('x2', height = 500)),
    column(3, verbatimTextOutput('x4')),
    column(4, verbatimTextOutput('x5'))
),

hr(),
```

)

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(seats, editable = "row", server = FALSE)

# highlight selected rows in the scatterplot
output$x2 = renderPlot({
    s = input$x1_rows_selected
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
    plot(seats$SeatNum, seats$y)
    if (length(s)) points(seats[s, , drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)
})

output$x4 = renderPrint({
    s = input$x1_rows_selected
    if (length(s)) {
        cat('Combined price \n of all seats:\n\n')
        cat(sum(seats[s,]$price))
    }
})

output$x5 = renderPrint({
    s2 = input$x1_rows_selected
    if (length(s2)) {
        cat('Total number of seats selected:\n\n')
        cat(length(s2))
    }
})
```

})

Upon launching the app I can select any of the first three rows and the plot reacts appropriately. However, from row 4 onwards the plot does not respond. I've played around with the `if (length(s)) points(seats[s, , drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)` line but I don't understand its behavior.

Comment: I notice your data.table has a column named Row, but in your call to plot you refer to RowNum

Comment: Sorry just a copy-paste typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table used in the linked example has two columns only, so for the `points` function its unambiguous what values go to `x` and `y`. But your table has multiple columns, so the indexing `seats[s, , drop=FALSE]` returns the selected rows and *all* columns:

```
> seats[1:2, , drop=FALSE]
   ID Row SeatNum y price
1:  1   A       1 1    45
2:  2   A       2 1    45
```

So, when indexing this way, `points` does not know what to map to `x` and `y`. You need to index the selected rows *and* the columns needed for `points` (in the correct order) to highlight points on the plot:

```
> seats[1:2, c("SeatNum", "y"), drop=FALSE]
   SeatNum y
1:       1 1
2:       2 1
```

---

Working app:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

seats = data.table(
  ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  Row = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  SeatNum = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  y = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  price = 45
)

ui <-
  fluidPage(title = 'Select Table Rows',

            h1('A Client-side Table'),

            fluidRow(
              column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x1')),
              column(6, plotOutput('x2', height = 500)),
              column(3, verbatimTextOutput('x4')),
              column(4, verbatimTextOutput('x5'))
            ),

            hr())

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(seats, editable = "row", server = FALSE)

  # highlight selected rows in the scatterplot
  output$x2 = renderPlot({
    s = input$x1_rows_selected
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
    plot(seats$SeatNum, seats$y)
    if (length(s))
      points(seats[s, c("SeatNum", "y") , drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)
  })

  output$x4 = renderPrint({
    s = input$x1_rows_selected
    if (length(s)) {
      cat('Combined price \n of all seats:\n\n')
      cat(sum(seats[s, ]$price))
    }
  })

  output$x5 = renderPrint({
    s2 = input$x1_rows_selected
    if (length(s2)) {
      cat('Total number of seats selected:\n\n')
      cat(length(s2))
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Gah I was so close but thanks for the fix! What a legend!